# Reading a value from root node XML

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have this  XML : 
   Type A:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <nfeProc versao="2.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
 </nfeProc>
```

Type B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cancCTe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="1.04"> 
</cancCTe>
```

Type C:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cteProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="1.04">
</cteProc>
```

I have read the root node with this :

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.Load(nomear);
 XmlNodeList ml = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("*");
 XmlNode primer = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
 exti = primer.Name;
```

With this code I read `nfeProc`, `cancTE`, and `cteProc`.

How can I read the value of `versao`?

Answer (score 3):

As you are using **C# 3.5 or later**, you can take advantage of LINQ to XML (your tag says you are using C# 4.0, so it certainly applies)

```
//your xml contents. I've just escaped " symbols, so I can use it as literal
string str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n "+
                 "<nfeProc versao=\"2.00\" xmlns=\"http://www" +
                 ".portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\">\r\n </nfeProc>";

var xml = XDocument.Parse(str);

Console.WriteLine(xml.Root.Attribute("versao").Value);
```

prints:

```
2.00
```

Comment: LINQ to XML is available starting in .NET 3.5, not 4

Comment: @elmugrat yes, sure, he just mentioned `C#-4` in tags, so he **can** use it in .net 4.

Comment: True, but it's easy to misread your first sentence as "If you are using C# 4.0"...I know I did  ;)

Answer (score 0):

See docs fro GetAttribute method or Attributes Property. 
There's also an example there

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.getattribute(v=vs.71).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.attributes(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
primer.Attributes["versao"].Value
```

You may also find this helpful:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("PATH TO YOUR .XML");
string value = doc.Element("nfeProc").Attribute("versao").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code:

```
string attribute = primer.Attributes["versao"].Value;
```